# Query the same column from the same table twice with group by

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following query which gives me a count of the patient requests in the past 2 weeks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_posts.post_author, COUNT(table_posts.post_author) AS leaderboard, 
table_users.ID, table_users.display_name, f.meta_value
    FROM table_posts
      INNER JOIN table_users
      ON table_posts.post_author = table_users.ID
      INNER JOIN table_frm_items
      ON table_posts.post_author=table_frm_items.user_id AND table_frm_items.form_id='11'
      INNER JOIN table_frm_item_metas AS f
      ON table_frm_items.id=f.item_id AND f.field_id='134'
    WHERE table_posts.post_type = 'patient_requests' AND (table_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2017-10-15' AND '2017-11-01')
    GROUP BY table_posts.post_author
    ORDER BY leaderboard DESC
```

I want to modify this query to add another column that compares the results of the previous 2 weeks. So current column gives me the count of the requests received between Oct 15 - Nov 1, the column I want to add is to compare that with the previous timeline of Oct 1 - Oct 15. I've looked for a simple solution but haven't found one. I feel like this shouldn't be complicated but I have tried multiple solutions including the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_posts.post_author, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (table_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2017-10-15' AND '2017-11-01') THEN table_posts.post_author ELSE 0 END) AS leaderboard1, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (table_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-15') THEN table_posts.post_author ELSE 0 END) AS leaderboard2, 
    table_users.display_name, f.meta_value
    FROM table_posts
      INNER JOIN table_users
      ON table_posts.post_author = table_users.ID
      INNER JOIN table_frm_items
      ON table_posts.post_author=table_frm_items.user_id AND table_frm_items.form_id='11'
      INNER JOIN table_frm_item_metas AS f
      ON table_frm_items.id=f.item_id AND f.field_id='134'
    WHERE table_posts.post_type IN ('patient_requests') AND (table_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-11-01')
    GROUP BY table_posts.post_author
    ORDER BY leaderboard1 DESC
```

But the cases were just completely ignored and I was given whatever is inside the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` counts the number of non-`null` values it gets. Since `0` is not a `null`, it's also counted. You could change your `else` clauses to explicitly return `null`, or just omit those clauses, as `case` by default returns `null` for values not matched in any clause:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2017-10-15' AND '2017-11-01' 
           THEN wp_posts.post_author 
      END) AS leaderboard1, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-15') 
          THEN wp_posts.post_author
      END) AS leaderboard2,
```